# Simple assembly loop [beginner] - where are the conditions and why register value is automatically decreasing

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, x86

I'm taking my first steps into assembly x86 on Windows.

My question is why does `ecx` decrease with each loop, and why does the program know when to break the loop?

I'm posting the code, debugger output and some comments

Code:

```
.386    
.model  flat

.data
intArray DWORD  1h,2h,3h,4h;

.code
start proc 
    mov edi,OFFSET intArray
    mov ecx,LENGTHOF intArray
    mov eax,0

LP: 
    add eax,[edi]
    add edi,TYPE intArray
    loop LP 
    ret

start endp 
end
```

In the debugger I can see that with each loop the value of `ecx` decreases by one:

```
LP 0:
    ecx = 4
LP 1:
    ecx = 3
LP 2:
    ecx = 2
LP 3:
    ecx = 1
LP 4:
    ecx = 0
```

At the begining `mov ecx,LENGTHOF intArray` it's moving `4` to `ecx`.

According to the docs

```
LENGTHOF
Returns the number of data objects in variable.
```

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-lengthof?view=msvc-170
  it should simply move value `4` into `ecx`, there is no information about tracking the `intArray` and updating it in runtime, so why it is decreasing?

If I understand the code correctly, it should work like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int intArray[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    
    int *edi = intArray;
    int ecx = sizeof(intArray) / sizeof(int);
    int eax = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
        eax += *edi;
        ecx -= 1;
        edi = (int*)(((intptr_t)edi) + sizeof(int));
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

but in assembly language the `for loop` condition and ecx decrementation are missing (I don't know where to look for it).

Is it hidden in flags?

Maybe someone could recommend a source that explains this problem?

Thank you!

Registers output

1. stopped at the line `add edi,TYPE intArray`

```
EAX = 00000001 EBX = 01028000 ECX = 00000004 EDX = 00A71005 ESI = 00A71005 EDI = 00A74000 EIP = 00A71021 ESP = 012FFDAC EBP = 012FFDB8 EFL = 00000202 

OV = 0 UP = 0 EI = 1 PL = 0 ZR = 0 AC = 0 PE = 0 CY = 0
```

2. stopped at the line `add edi,TYPE intArray`

```
EAX = 00000003 EBX = 01028000 ECX = 00000003 EDX = 00A71005 ESI = 00A71005 EDI = 00A74004 EIP = 00A71021 ESP = 012FFDAC EBP = 012FFDB8 EFL = 00000206 

OV = 0 UP = 0 EI = 1 PL = 0 ZR = 0 AC = 0 PE = 1 CY = 0
```

3. stopped at the line `add edi,TYPE intArray`

```
EAX = 00000006 EBX = 01028000 ECX = 00000002 EDX = 00A71005 ESI = 00A71005 EDI = 00A74008 EIP = 00A71021 ESP = 012FFDAC EBP = 012FFDB8 EFL = 00000206 

OV = 0 UP = 0 EI = 1 PL = 0 ZR = 0 AC = 0 PE = 1 CY = 0
```

4. stopped at the line `add edi,TYPE intArray`

```
EAX = 0000000A EBX = 01028000 ECX = 00000001 EDX = 00A71005 ESI = 00A71005 EDI = 00A7400C EIP = 00A71021 ESP = 012FFDAC EBP = 012FFDB8 EFL = 00000206 

OV = 0 UP = 0 EI = 1 PL = 0 ZR = 0 AC = 0 PE = 1 CY = 0
```

5. stopped at the line `ret`

```
EAX = 0000000A EBX = 01028000 ECX = 00000000 EDX = 00A71005 ESI = 00A71005 EDI = 00A74010 EIP = 00A71026 ESP = 012FFDAC EBP = 012FFDB8 EFL = 00000212 

OV = 0 UP = 0 EI = 1 PL = 0 ZR = 0 AC = 1 PE = 0 CY = 0
```

Comment: The x86 instruction set it very well documented, with plenty of tutorials and references all over the Internet. If you check one of the references, what does it say about the instructions you use?

Comment: And, assuming that you yourself wrote the assembly code shown, how did you do it without fully knowing what each instruction does? For example, why did you use the `loop` instruction? Was you told to use it by someone or something? Who or what told you to use the `loop` instruction? Did he or she (or the book or tutorial) say why you should use it, or try to explain what it does?

Comment: Hey, no I didn't wrote this, I'm not a magician: p

For now, I look around and browse through various tutorials to roughly know the basics before I sit down to serious sources.

This code has been discussed as summing up the elements of an array and the topics I am asking about have not been explained. 

I have described everything I understood and included my understanding in c. I'm asking in general, maybe there is a simple answer that will allow me to go further - at least will give me a general understanding.

Comment: Then you should *definitely* find a reference about the `loop` instruction. :)

Comment: Ok, I'll follow this tip, thanks :p